# Exctract a value from a Json file(python)

Tags: python, arrays, json, list, floating-point

Hi i'm not an expert and this problem kept me stuck for such a long time I hope that someone here can help me
i would like to exctract the value "interestExpense" from the following json file:

```
{'incomeBeforeTax': 17780000000, 
'minorityInterest': 103000000, 
'netIncome': 17937000000, 
'sellingGeneralAdministrative': 5918000000, 
'grossProfit': 16507000000, 
'ebit': 10589000000, 
'endDate': 1640908800, 
'operatingIncome': 10589000000, 
'interestExpense': -1803000000, 
'incomeTaxExpense': -130000000, 
'totalRevenue': 136341000000, 
'totalOperatingExpenses': 125752000000, 
'costOfRevenue': 119834000000, 
'totalOtherIncomeExpenseNet': 7191000000, 
'netIncomeFromContinuingOps': 17910000000, 
'netIncomeApplicableToCommonShares': 17937000000}
```

In this case the result should be -130000000 as a string but i m trying to find a way to create an list(or an array) with all those floats so that i can decide which one to pick, i have no idea how to manipulate this kind of data(json)
For example

```
print(list[0])
```

should return  17780000000(the value associated with incomeBeforeTax)
is this actually possible?
The output is generated from this code:

```
annual_is_stms=[]
url_financials ='https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/{}/financials?p{}'
stock= 'F'

response = requests.get(url_financials.format(stock,stock),headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,'html.parser')
pattern = re.compile(r'\s--\sData\s--\s')
script_data = soup.find('script',text=pattern).contents[0]

script_data[:500]

script_data[-500:]

start = script_data.find("context")-2
json_data =json.loads(script_data[start:-12])
json_data['context']['dispatcher']['stores']['QuoteSummaryStore'].keys()

#all data relative financials

annual_is=json_data['context']['dispatcher']['stores']['QuoteSummaryStore']['incomeStatementHistory']['incomeStatementHistory']
for s in annual_is:
    statement = {}
    for key, val in s.items():
        try:
            statement[key] = val['raw']
        except TypeError:
            continue
        except KeyError:
            continue
    annual_is_stms.append(statement)
print(annual_is_stms[0])
```

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: my bad PYTHON i m editing the post

Comment: Your snippet of 'code' looks like a python dict and not json. Perhaps you could include the code that produces this output.

Comment: why you don't just say `result['incomeBeforeTax']` to get 17780000000 value?

Comment: i edited to post to make it more clear

Comment: How can I know that the output is generated from the code you added? There are no `print()` statements.

Comment: there is for some reason it did not upload i just edited it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using python, you need to include the json module and parse it as an object:

```
import json

# some JSON:
x =  '{ "name":"John", "age":30, "city":"New York"}'

# parse x:
y = json.loads(x)

# the result is a Python dictionary:
print(y["age"])
```

Regards

L.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the output snippet you posted comes from this line:

`print(annual_is_stms[0])`

If you now want the: `-1803000000` you should do:

`print(annual_is_stms[0]['interestExpense'])`

If you want the: `-130000000` you should do:

`print(annual_is_stms[0]['incomeTaxExpense'])`

and if you want the: `17780000000` you should do:

`print(annual_is_stms[0]['incomeBeforeTax'])`

Answer (score -1):

Copy and paste this into Python.

```
data = {'incomeBeforeTax': 17780000000, 
'minorityInterest': 103000000, 
'netIncome': 17937000000, 
'sellingGeneralAdministrative': 5918000000, 
'grossProfit': 16507000000, 
'ebit': 10589000000, 
'endDate': 1640908800, 
'operatingIncome': 10589000000, 
'interestExpense': -1803000000, 
'incomeTaxExpense': -130000000, 
'totalRevenue': 136341000000, 
'totalOperatingExpenses': 125752000000, 
'costOfRevenue': 119834000000, 
'totalOtherIncomeExpenseNet': 7191000000, 
'netIncomeFromContinuingOps': 17910000000, 
'netIncomeApplicableToCommonShares': 17937000000}

print(data['interestExpense'])
```

Comment: At first it was not working but after a few attempts i managed to use the correct syntax thank you for your support